# Laravel 5.1 Package Dependancies Error

Tags: laravel, package

I am developing a package in L5.1.

Listed https://github.com/crodas/TextRank as a dependancy and composer has pulled it in.

Added `$this->app->register('crodas\TextRank\Config’);` to the register method in my service provider but when I try to run the application I get a `Class 'crodas\TextRank\Config not found error

I am sure that I am just missing something small! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

For integrating that package with Laravel you neeed to create a custom service provider. [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers#writing-service-providers) have a very good example of the full procedure which for your case would be similar to:

Create a service provider

```
php artisan make:provider TextRankServiceProvider
```

Customize service provider (file `app/Providers/TextRankServiceProvider.php`)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use crodas\TextRank\Config;
use crodas\TextRank\TextRank;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TextRankServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Register bindings in the container.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('TextRank', function ($app) {
            $config   = new Config;
            return new TextRank($config);
        });
    }
}
```

[Register service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers#registering-providers) by adding `App\Providers\TextRankServiceProvider::class` to file `config/app.php`

For using the package

```
$keywords = app('TextRank')->getKeywords($some_long_text);
```

NOTE: The code has not been actually tested. I just followed TextRank package and Laravel instructions.

Comment: Hey Javi, I am still getting the Class 'crodas\TextRank\Config not found error. I also had tried to simply follow along with both docs. Any other ideas? I find it strange that the error line is in the register method and not the use statement at the top.

Comment: I've now tried the code and it works. `Class not found` means Composer was not able to find the class. Did you install the package with Composer? To do so add  `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to your `composer.json file` and the run `composer require crodas/text-rank`

Comment: As I said in the original post I am using this as a dependancy of my own package. I managed to get this to work by including composers autoload file at the top of your example.